# Trying to call Intel Visual Fortran function from Visual C

Tags: c, visual-studio, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding, mixed-programming

I have two projects: `CPart` and `FortranPart` in my solution. `FortranPart` depends on `CPart` and the later contains the `main` function. Here is code of the `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int __stdcall FORTRAN_ADD(int *A, int *B);

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    int c = FORTRAN_ADD(&a, &b);

    printf("%i\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is code of my fortran module

```
module FORTRAN_UTILS

implicit none

contains

integer*4 function fortran_add(a, b) result(c)
implicit none
integer*4, intent(in) :: a, b
c = a + b
end function fortran_add

end module FORTRAN_UTILS
```

After the fortran is compiled I get the file `FortranPart.lib`. In `CPart` project dependencies I added it as external library. When I try to compile and run `CPart` I get the following

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _FORTRAN_ADD@8 referenced in function _main  CPart   c:\Users\sasha\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MSCourse\MSCourse\main.obj 1
```

P.S.
I need the main program to be in C, not C++.

Comment: There really many many many  questions and answers here about this problem. Did you try to read some at all? Why do you use the `__stdcall FORTRAN_ADD`? Why stdcall at all? Why capital letters? Do you compile 32bit or 64bit? Which compiler version?

Answer (score 0):

A little more research brought me this page
https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/node/678422

I changed my code a little and now it's working.

```
subroutine fortran_add(a, b, r) bind(c)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer (c_int), value :: a, b
    integer (c_int), intent(out) :: r
    r = a + b
    end subroutine fortran_add
```

and `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fortran_add(int a, int b, int *r);

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    int c;

    fortran_add(a, b, &c);

    printf("%i\n", c);

    scanf_s("");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There was no need to search for that link, just look around here before asking! Or just read the wiki of the tag I added [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding].